# iOS 6 slide push controller animation in iOS 7

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am creating an application and wants to use same iOS 6 style right to left slide push controller animation in iOS 7. iOS 7 changed the default controller push animation.

How can i get previous animation?

If you found this question duplicate, then please give me the answer link before any comment.

Thanks for your time.

Let me clear one more thing.

I have controller that have a custom view of size (320x400) in iOS 7. I use a UINavigationController (_homeInnerNavigationCtrl) that will add more controllers init and this _homeInnerNavigationCtrl.view is subView in custom view. So when i try to use this code:

```
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [currentViewCtrl.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [currentViewCtrl presentViewController:targetCtrl animated:NO completion:^{
        [_homeInnerNavigationCtrl pushViewController:targetViewCtrl animated:NO];
    }];
```

It gives me crash: 
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller  as a child of view controller:'**

Hope you will understand the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While presenting controller use this code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

and when you dismiss, use this code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for for response but presentModalViewController is DEPRECATED is iOS 6 and i am working on iOS 7.

Comment: @Jack_iPhone - You can use [self presentViewController: animated: completion:] - i guess this method should work